# Set exchange body to null

Tags: xml, apache-camel

I am trying to set null into the body of the exchange in xml definiton like this:

```
<camel:setBody>
    <camel:constant>null</camel:constant>
</camel:setBody>
```

or like this:

```
<camel:setBody>
    <camel:simple>null</camel:simple>
</camel:setBody>
```

they all give string "null" in the end.

Any idea about What the right form is?

Comment: <setBody><simple></simple></setBody> works for me in XML notation in Camel 2.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
<camel:setBody>
    <camel:simple>${bodyAs(null)}</camel:simple>
</camel:setBody>
```

Comment: This gave me "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: null" errors with camel 2.17.7

Comment: Same CNFE here with 3.11.3

Answer (score 3):

I'm working with Talend ESB (camel 2.17). 
I done it in javaDSL. This worked good to me :

```
.setBody().simple("${null}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<camel:setBody>
    <camel:simple>${null}</camel:simple>
</camel:setBody>
```

Comment: it says "there is no operator as null" or something like that

Comment: below cod is working, <route id="timerToLog">
    <from uri="timer:foo?period=5000"/>
    <setBody>
      <simple>${bodyAs(null)}</simple>
    </setBody>
    <log message="The message contains ${body.getClass} "/>
   <!--  <to uri="mock:result"/> -->
  </route>

Comment: In camel 3.11.3, this is the only thing that works

Answer (score 0):

**In Camel 2.15.x** I was doing this that way (and it worked):

```
<camel:setBody>
    <camel:simple resultType="java.lang.String">null</camel:simple>
</camel:setBody>
```

In recent versions of Camel it might be changed

Comment: This worked for me.  I was initially worried that the above logic would be set the body to the String value "null", but I added a PMD debugging via "<choice><when><simple>${body} == null</simple><log>it works</log>" and it was indeed null.

Comment: but it is not null... Reading the body in normal java code in camel 3.11.3 and doing a 'body == null' returns false since it is "null" (the string)

Comment: the logic on apache camel site probably changed from year 2015 and camel version 2.15. I'm not using Camel anymore, so I have no idea how to do it now. I added disclaimer